# websocket cannot connect via apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, websocket

I am using the [terminado](https://github.com/jupyter/terminado) and i am running the `unique.py` inside the demo folder on port `9090` from inside a docker container with a ip of `172.17.0.2`

So i have set up a reverse proxy using apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName  terminal.local
    ServerAlias terminal.kide
    DocumentRoot /home/satnam-sandhu/Workstation/virtualhost
    <Directory />
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
          Require all granted
    </Proxy>
       ProxyPass / http://172.17.0.2:9090/
       ProxyPassReverse /  http://172.17.0.2:9090/
       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/local.kide-error.log
       LogLevel error
       CustomLog /var/log/apache2/local.kide-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

when i access`http://terminal.local` from my browser it get this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://terminal.local/websocket' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

What am i supposed to do?

Here is the error log:

```
[Mon Jun 25 16:13:43.072784 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 14905:tid 139981405693696] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9090 (127.0.0.1) failed 
[Mon Jun 25 16:13:43.072892 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 14905:tid 139981405693696] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s 
[Mon Jun 25 16:13:43.072900 2018] [proxy_http:error] [pid 14905:tid 139981405693696] [client 127.0.0.1:34494] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1 
[Mon Jun 25 16:13:43.486626 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 14905:tid 139981397300992] AH00940: HTTP: disabled connection for (127.0.0.1) 
[Mon Jun 25 16:57:24.538726 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 1954:tid 140063423616768] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9090 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Mon Jun 25 16:57:24.688176 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 1954:tid 140063423616768] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s 
[Mon Jun 25 16:57:24.688220 2018] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1954:tid 140063423616768] [client 127.0.0.1:45860] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1 
[Mon Jun 25 16:57:25.290133 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 1954:tid 140063406831360] AH00940: HTTP: disabled connection for (127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: Did you look at your Apache logfiles? They will explain why you got HTTP error code `400`.

Comment: i have included the error log in the question, sir.

Comment: Connection refused: AH00957 looks like a good start to search for.

however this might not even be the first request as the worker seems to have been disabled after it. Please add the first request (or wait at least 1min so the worker is back online, and verify that it actually is) when you try to connect.